# Is there any physical, readable difference between a JSON string and a JSONP string?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I've modified my WebAPI to return JSONP, but how can I tell if it's really JSONP and not regular JSON?  I understand that the "P" stands for Padding.  Is there a physical, readable difference between JSON and JSONP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsonp will be in the form of this:  (returned by the server of course)

```
"callbackFunction( { jsonSyntax } );"
```

jsonp is just JSON but with a callback javascript function wrapping it.

Comment: So the string that my WebAPI returns, should the callback function start the string?

Comment: You must remember my question from yesterday! :)  Yes, I will be calling it from Ajax, but for testing purposes, I'm navigating straight to the WebAPI's URL, and the JSON is outputted to my browser window.  If I understand you correctly, the JSON I see in my browser should have the callback function at the beginning, right?

Comment: yes.  the wep api content type should be set to json also.  typically I send the callback in the query string to the server, then I generate my json..  ultimately i respond back with "<myCallbackFunction>( <json> );"